# What should be the receivers 'userId' to establish a Sinch App-to-App call?

Tags: ios, sinch

This seems to be a basic question when using Sinch for the first time. 
At first when we setup a `SINClient` on the app we need to set a `userId` value. It says that *"The User ID should uniquely identify the user on the particular device"*. So I used my device UUID for that.

`uuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]`

To call another user using App-To-App calling, I created a `SINCall` using `- (id<SINCall>)callUserWithId:(NSString *)userId`. Here I need to provide the recipient's `userId`.

What should be that value? Is that the one he used to setup `SINClient` in his App? If so, I need to store all users `userId` values in a remote server to establish calls correctly? Or is there any other way/values(like mobile number) to set `userIds`?

I wanted to know the recomended way of using Sinch. *Thanks in advance*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Identifier for vendor, thats what you should call on the other side as well. The whole concept with sinch relies on that you have a userdatabase so if you use UUID you need to save UUID in your database and display the contact list for that user with maybe uuid hidden and show a friendly name to the user

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So as per my understanding, Sinch will uniquely identify a user I want to call using the application(registered in sinch) and the userId. Right?

Comment: yeah, you just need to keep track of the ids and you are golden